# java inheritance in array

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, casting

Let's say I have a parent class with toString() that returns "parent". Then, I override this method in the child class so that it returns "child". If I put the child in an array of Parents, then call toString() without any casting, which method will be called?

Please respond ASAP,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check it yourself.

Comment: Hint: `toString` is a "virtual" method. What does it mean (in Java) if a method is "virtual"?

Comment: Inheritence 101: In a pointer array (every object in Java is a pointer), it will always call the most specific method, if available. That's the most basic use of classes.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Usually. Except if the method is not virtual. (C# methods are not virtual by default.)

Comment: 9 downvotes couldn't deduct any points, 1 upvote gave 5 points. I won

Comment: @user2141449 , btW you have one answer on your question, and you should accept that answer.

Comment: Only one question downvoted to -6 and even has 16 points. Stackoverflow is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

It will invoke the `toString` method of the subclass.

Comment: thanks, and to others who reported this, how is it not a real question? and I didn't see it until now, so calm down. dummies. not everyone posts a question and sits and waits for an answer